# Azure SQL Server database with visual studio subscription

Tags: azure

I wanted to learn Azure SQL Server database and I created pay as you go account with Microsoft but I ended up with subscription to Visual studio premium edition with MSDN also
My question is do I need to have visual studio premium subscription? in order to learn Azure SQL server data

Comment: I got an Azure account with my current employer.
Thanks
Oded Dror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not matter what kind of Visual Studio you have, you just need an azure subscription then you can create your own Azure SQL Server and DB. And probably you should use SQL Server Management Studio instead of Visual Studio for SQL Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Here is a step by step guide how to create an SQL Azure DB: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-get-started

Comment: Tamas,

Thank you
Oded Dror